# Listing all txt files from and folder and adding string at one line in all txt files

Tags: java

I am trying to list all txt files in a directory, read the txt files one by one and edit one line in the same txt file. Continue to do same for all other txt files. My txt file changed to blank when I tried the below code. Please help.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String dir = "C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\XX";
        String line = null;
        File folder = new File(dir);
        String[] files = folder.list();
        for (String file : files) {
            try {
                File f = new File(dir + "\\" + file);
                if (file.endsWith(".ind")) {
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(f);
                    // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    while ((bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (line.contains("GROUP_FILENAME:"))
                            s = line.substring(0, 15) + "/HOME/FOLDER/" + line.substring(15);
                        lines.add(s);
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                    fileReader.close();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    for (String st : lines)
                        out.write(st);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + "'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you assign only once before the while loop the line variable. The other readLine() in the while condition go to nowhere.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. I added readLIne() in the while condition, still no luck!

Comment: There is no else-branch for line if it doesn't contains GROUP_FILENAME:

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight change, hope this would work.

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*; 
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    String s = null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String dir = "C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\XX" ;
        String line = null;
        File folder = new File(dir);
       String[] files = folder.list();
        for (String file : files) 
        {
            try {
            File f = new File(dir + "\\" +file);
          if (file.endsWith(".ind")){  
            FileReader fileReader =  new FileReader(f);
            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(fileReader);
           // line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if ( line.contains("GROUP_FILENAME:"))
        s = line.substring(0, 15) + "/HOME/FOLDER/" + line.substring(15);
      lines.add(s);
      System.out.println(s);
            }       
                fileReader.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      for(String st : lines)
        out.write(st);
      out.flush();
      out.close();

          }         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println( "Unable to open file '" + "'");                
        }    
        }
           }
}
```

Comment: What happens to the line if it doesn't contains GROUP_FILENAME:? I think it should be written to the file unchanged.

Comment: Yes, it that case null or previous content of s would be added to lines. As the contents of files was not posted so we assume that files contains "GROUP_FILENAME"

Comment: Ralf.. Every file will contain GROUP_FILENAME

Comment: Uzair. I tried above, all the content in the text file is cleared , I can only see a blank file

Comment: I have tried myself and it was working on my machine

Comment: something I was looking for, +1 for the solution.